# Elixir + Phoenix : __MODULE__ undefined inside a quote

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

(code citation has been anonymized)

In my phoenix models I have some methods which are redundant, like this basic one :

```
  def build(params) do
    changeset(%__MODULE__{}, params)
  end
```

Since I put them inside my model modules, they work fine, but I want to avoid code duplication and I want to make them available to all my models through a helper module like this :

```
defmodule MyApp.Helpers.Model do
  defmodule Changeset do
    defmacro __using__(_opts) do
      quote do
        def build(params) do
          changeset(%__MODULE__{}, params)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Doing this, I'm getting an error :

```
== Compilation error on file lib/my_app/model/my_model.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/my_app/model/my_model.ex:3: MyApp.Model.MyModel.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct MyApp.Model.MyModel
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
```

The related model looks basically like this :

```
defmodule MyApp.Model.MyModel do
  use MyApp.Helpers, :model
  use MyApp.Helpers.Model.Changeset # here for comprehension, should be in MyApp.Helpers quoted :model method

  schema "my_table" do
    field :name, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @required_fields ~w(name)a
  @optional_fields ~w()
  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name]}

  def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields)
    |> cast(params, @optional_fields)
    |> validate_required(@required_fields)
    |> validate_format(:name, ~r/^[a-z]{3,}$/)
    |> unique_constraint(:name)
  end
end
```

I'm thinking that's because the module is not yet defined at compile time within the macro, but I'm not sure, nor how to fix this and make it works.

Some lights here would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you also post the code of the module you're `use`ing this module in?

Comment: You should probably swap `use MyApp.Helpers.Model` and `defstruct MyModel` lines in the `MyModel` module to be the latter (struct declaration) going first.

Comment: Ok, following @mudasobwa suggestion, I put the `use MyApp.Helpers.Model.Changeset` after the `schema` invocation which is generating the struct in `MyModel` and it works. So I guess there's no way to put this `use` globally in the phoenix usual `MyApp.Helpers, :model` since we need the schema define first ?

Comment: @Dogbert I added the `MyModel` definition in the question, thanks.

Comment: You might achieve this functionality using [`@after_compile`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Module.html#module-compile-callbacks) callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the struct is defined by calling the `defstruct` macro, and cannot be used earlier, since the compiler has no idea how to expand it. In case of ecto schemas the struct is declared by the `schema` macro underneath.

Fortunately, looking the documentation of `defstruct` we can see it creates a function called `__struct__/0` on the module where the struct is declared. And functions can call other local functions, even before they are defined! Using that knowledge we can change your macro to:

```
defmodule MyApp.Helpers.Model do
  defmodule Changeset do
    defmacro __using__(_opts) do
      quote do
        def build(params) do
          changeset(__struct__(), params)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That said, defining functions in `__using__` is generally considered a bad practice, as stated in the documentation for [`Kernel.use/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Kernel.html#use/2)

> Finally, developers should also avoid defining functions inside the
>   `__using__/1` callback, unless those functions are the default implementation of a previously defined `@callback` or are functions
>   meant to be overridden (see `defoverridable/1`. Even in these cases,
>   defining functions should be seen as a “last resource”.

Defining functions in `__using__` has many downsides including: slow compilation (the function is compiled over and over in every module it's injected to), difficulty in debugging ("where is this coming from?") and poor compostability.

A much better approach might be to define a single, reusable function. For example:

```
defmodule MyApp.SchemaUtils do
  def build(schema, params) do
    schema.changeset(struct(schema), params)
  end
end
```

PS. The `@derive` calls have to be declared before the struct.

Comment: Thanks for this well detailed answer !